# How do i check the wifi switch in between my data uploading

Tags: ios, swift, wifi

**I need an event or like an observer while switching between wifi networks or wifi to cellular and vice versa**. Can anybody help me with it? **I am uploading a video file and while uploading I am switching between wifi networks or auto-switch between cellular to wifi. So need an event for the same**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is included in the example on the Reachability [github](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) page

```
//declare this property where it won't go out of scope relative to your listener
let reachability = try! Reachability()

//declare this inside of viewWillAppear

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(note:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    do{
      try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
      print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }
```

And the method

```
@objc func reachabilityChanged(note: Notification) {

  let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

  switch reachability.connection {
  case .wifi:
      print("Reachable via WiFi")
  case .cellular:
      print("Reachable via Cellular")
  case .unavailable:
    print("Network not reachable")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the device is connected or not, you can use `NWPathMonitor`, like this:

```
import Network

struct ConnectivityMonitor {
    static let monitor = NWPathMonitor()

    static func setup() {
        ConnectivityMonitor.monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            //path.isExpensive tells you whether the user is using cellular data as opposed to wifi. "true" if cellular data.
            
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                //Connected
            } else {
                //Not connected
            }
        }

        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")
        ConnectivityMonitor.monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

Comment: For network connectivity, I have used reachability. What I need is if you have 2 wifi connections you switched wifi_1 to wifi_2 this event I need to monitor.